# Use the HTML 'script' tag in a JavaScript file with the innerHTML keyword

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome

I am using the innerHTML keyword in a JavaScript file. This innerHTML code works fine and the result is correctly displayed in the browser. However, I also want to import some icons from an external JavaScript file. How could I do this?

I have tried to write the  statement in the HTML file. I have also tried to write the  statement inside the innerHTML section of the JavaScript file. However, the icons are not displayed.

When I import the icons from the HTML document, and also use the icons in the HTML document, this works as expected. However, when I try to use the icons inside the innerHTML section of the JavaScript file, this does not work.

For example, I have this HTML code:

```
<head>
<script src="The link to the source of the script"></script>
</head>
```

and this JavaScript code:

```
const headerTemplate = document.createElement('template');

headerTemplate.innerHTML = `
  <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
`
```

This code should be added directly into the body tag of the document, instead of inside a class or div.

Comment: maybe you are missing to include the fontawesome assets and that's why you can't see the icons when those elements get created via js?

Comment: and by the way are you aware that the template element doesn't get rendered? but it requires you to clone its content and append it to the dom?

Comment: I am using the online kit from Font Awsome, the assets are not on my PC.

Comment: you are not answering the question.. anyway anything to say about the answer given? I need to understand where are the missing points in your question that still were not addressed

Comment: the point is that to include the asset you need the `<link>` element to define where is the css file to include to the page. You need(!) that part. Did you mean to include it directly statically in the html or you wanted it to be added dynamically?

Comment: I have got the assets from font awsome online. These assets should be imported using the <script> statement. When I ran all of the webpage using HTML, the assets displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are some critical points here to make sure of:

- missing to include the FontAwesome assets with the element `<link rel="stylesheet".../>` in the html?
- `createElement('template')` returns a `<template>` element that doesn't work like regular elements. Here in this demo I used a `<div>`
- The element just created needs to be appended to the dom to render it to screen

```js
const headerTemplate = document.createElement('div');
headerTemplate.innerHTML = '<i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>';

document.querySelector('body').append(headerTemplate);
```

```css
body{
  font-size: 50px;
  outline: solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<body>
</body>
```

Comment: 'Nuff said. You could also use document.getElementById('target').style.outline("solid") if you want it all in one javascript file.

Comment: Could I add the icon into directly into the <body> tag, instead of inside an ID?

Comment: @Autex that css rule I added to show the outline of #target was just to better highlight the fact the icon was actually working. We have a very confused question here that actually deserved much more focus before any answer was given. But I've got this bad habit lately to just give very obvious answers with too many not requested details

Comment: @Diego Hmm I understood the question like you did :-D

Comment: @user20936799 sure.. I added the icon to the body instead of adding it to the #target element